# An exercise from Apostol's book

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to solve following problem from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis. The problem could be very trivial, but I am not getting clue for it.

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[-2,2]$ such that 
>   $$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\le \frac{1}{8} |a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2| \,\,\,\, \mbox{ for all } n\ge 1.$$
>   Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

**Q.** Any hint for solving this? (I was not getting the restrictions of interval and the factor $\frac{1}{8}$).

My try: since $a_i\in [-2,2]$ so $a_i^2\in [0,4]$. Thus, $|a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2|\le 4$ and so $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\le \frac{1}{2}$. After this, I couldn't proceed.

Any HINT is sufficient.

Comment: Have a look at the sequence given by $b_n := a_{n+1}-a_n$. You may prove that $|b_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{2}|b_n|$. What happens next?

Comment: This will show that $b_n$ is convergent; but what about $a_n$?

Comment: It’s not that $\vert a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \vert \lt \frac 12$.  It’s that $\vert a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \vert \lt \frac 12 \vert a_{n+1}-a_n \vert$.  Use that fact to prove the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: A more general statement is as follows : let $x=(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose there exists $\rho\in(0,1)$ such that : $\forall n\geqslant1$, $\mid x_{n+1}-x_n\mid\leqslant\rho\mid x_n-x_{n-1}\mid$. Then $x$ is (a Cauchy sequence and thus) a convergent sequence.
Here we can take $\rho=\frac12$

Comment: @Beginner Recall that: The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It suffices to show that $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

By the the given condition, for $n\geq  1$, since $|a_n|\leq 2$,
$$\begin{align}|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|&\le \frac{1}{8} |a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2| =\frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}+a_n| |a_{n+1}-a_n|\\&\leq  \frac{2+2}{8} |a_{n+1}-a_n|=\frac{1}{2} |a_{n+1}-a_n|.
\end{align}$$
It follows that
$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{2} |a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^2} |a_{n}-a_{n-1}|\leq
\cdots\leq \frac{1}{2^n} |a_{2}-a_{1}|.$$
Hence if $n>m\geq 1$ then
$$|a_n-a_m|\leq |a_{2}-a_{1}|\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{2^k}\leq \frac{|a_{2}-a_{1}|}{2^{m-2}}\to 0$$
as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: My edit: A single missing brace bracket in the last displayed line prevented it from compiling.

Comment: Yes, but I corrected the last denominator from $2^{m-1}$ to $2^{m-2}$.

Comment: I didn't see that . I was just trying to find the compiling error :)

Answer (score 5):

HINT. Let $d_n=|a_{n+1}-a_n|.$ Then

$$
\begin{align}
d_{n+1}=|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| & \le |a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2|/8 \\
& = |a_{n+1}-a_n| \cdot |a_{n+1}+a_n|/8 \\
& \le |a_{n+1}-a_n| \cdot 4/8 \\
& = d_n/2.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_{m+1}^-:=\left|a_{m+1}-a_m\right|$ and $A_{m+1}^+:=\left|a_{m+1}+a_m\right|$ for convenience. Then for a positive integer $k$, \begin{align}A_{n+k+1}^-&\le\frac{1}{8}\left|a_{n+k}^2-a_{n+k-1}^2\right|=\frac{1}{8}A_{n+k}^+A_{n+k}^-\\&\le\frac{1}{8}A_{n+k}^+\cdot\frac18\left|a_{n+k-1}^2-a_{n+k-2}^2\right|=\frac1{8^2}A_{n+k}^+A_{n+k-1}^+A_{n+k-1}^-\\&\le\frac1{8^3}A_{n+k}^+A_{n+k-1}^+A_{n+k-2}^+A_{n+k-2}^-\\&\le\cdots\\&\le\frac{A_{n+k-(n+k-1)+1}^-}{8^{n+k-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n+k-1}A_{n-k-i+1}^+\\&\le\frac{A_2^-}{8^{n+k-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n+k-1}|2+2|\quad(\text{since}\, \left|a_j\right|\le2\quad\forall j\ge1)\\&=\frac{A_2^-}{2^{n+k-1}}\end{align} Therefore, as $k\to\infty$, we have $\left|a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+k}\right|\to0$ and convergence is shown.